# windows 7 hibernate won't resume

Tags: windows-7, hibernate

I've had Hibernate working on Windows 7 for quite a while... now I've noticed that when I try to resume from a Hibernate, instead of seeing "Resuming..." I see "Starting..." and then a message that Windows did not shut down properly.

What seems to be happening (to me) is that the Hibernate must not be completing properly, and instead of hibernating, the machine is just crashing.  Then when I turn it back on, it does not recognize that it hibernated and attempts to start instead, then noticing that it did not shut down properly.

The only recent change I've made to my system is to add PGP Disk Encryption, although the problem did not start immediately after that, but a week or so later, so I don't think it's related.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

See last post [here](http://forum.thinkpads.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=78912).

> I had this problem with a W500 and a clean install of Windows 7, with the Lenovo Power Manager.
>
> The fix was to open Power Manager, go to Global Power Settings, and under the Events category, tick 'apply to all power plans' and enable all the various sleep/resume triggers (Fn + Fn4, lid closed, power button).
>
> After this, the laptop now sleeps and resumes reliably.
>
> I think the Lenovo Power Manager takes over sleep event management from Windows, but doesn't actually know what to do until you define these defaults.

Is this Intel or AMD?